# How to read JBoss Resteasy's servlet request twice while maintaing @FormParam binding?

Tags: servlets, jboss, jax-rs, resteasy

I'm using JBoss' Resteasy as our JAX-RS provider. We have a requirement to read the servlet request body for authentication purpose, the problem is once the InputStream is read in the request, it cannot be read again, hence @FormParam won't work unless I can somehow "put the content back". I've tried the following two options:

1. Using Resteasy's PreProcessInterceptor, I was able to read the body, but there's no way to reset the InputStream or add a wrapper type. The [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.2.GA/userguide/html/Interceptors.html) doesn't mention anything about this. According to JBoss' [issue tracker](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-567), it's not currently possible.
2. Using the Servlet filter + Wrapper type apporach ([see example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449096/how-to-read-servletrequests-body-more-than-once)), I was able to get the request body in `@javax.ws.rs.core.Context HttpServletRequest request` but all the @FormParam still return null.

Here's a snippet of the PreProcessorInterceptor:

```
@Provider
@ServerInterceptor
public class SomePreprocessor implements PreProcessInterceptor {

    public ServerResponse preProcess(HttpRequest request, ResourceMethod method)
            throws Failure, WebApplicationException {
        try{
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            IOUtils.copy(request.getInputStream(), writer, "UTF-8");
            System.out.println("Request Body: "+writer.toString());

            // What can I do to reset the request body?
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Here's a snippet of the rest method:

```
@POST
@Path("/something")
@Produces("application/xml")
public Response doSomething(
  @FormParam("name") String name,
  @javax.ws.rs.core.Context HttpServletRequest request) {

  // name is always null
  System.out.println(name);

  // prints nothing in approach 1, returns the body in approach 2
  java.io.StringWriter writer = new java.io.StringWriter();
  org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(request.getReader(), writer);
  System.out.println(writer.toString());
}
```

Comment: Not really related to your question: Why are you using the body and not the header for that?

Comment: For security reason, I must authenticate a request base on the POST body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone is still interested in the answer, here's how I solved it:

Create a custom type that extends HttpServletRequestWrapper. Make sure you override

- getInputStream()
- getReader()
- getParameter()
- getParameterMap()
- getParameterNames()
- getParameterValues()

This is because when Resteasy tries to bind using @Form, @FormParam, and @QueryParam etc, it calls the getParameter() method on the Resteasy class, which is then delegated to the underlying request, in my case, Apache's Coyote Servlet Request. So overriding getInputStream() and getReader() alone are not enough, you must make sure that getParameter() utilize the new input stream as well.

If you want to store the body for later use, you must then construct the param map yourself by parsing the query string and url-encoded form body. It's quite straight forward to implement but it carries its own risk. I recommend reading Coyote's implementation of the same methods.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.servlet.ServletInputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

/**
 * Wrapper class that supports repeated read of the request body and parameters.
 */
public class CustomHttpServletRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CustomHttpServletRequest.class);

    // A typical url encoded form is "key1=value&key2=some%20value"
    public final static Pattern urlStrPattern = Pattern.compile("([^=&]+)=([^&]*)[&]?");

    // Cached request body
    protected ByteArrayOutputStream cachedBytes;

    protected String encoding;
    protected String requestBody;

    // Cached form parameters
    protected Map<String, String[]> paramMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String[]>();

    // Cached header names, including extra headers we injected.
    protected Enumeration<?> headerNames = null;

    /**
     * 
     * @param request
     */
    public CustomHttpServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);

        // Read the body and construct parameters
        try{
            encoding = (request.getCharacterEncoding()==null)?"UTF-8":request.getCharacterEncoding();

            // Parameters in query strings must be added to paramMap
            String queryString = request.getQueryString();
            logger.debug("Extracted HTTP query string: "+queryString);
            if(queryString != null && !queryString.isEmpty()){
                addParameters(queryString, encoding);
            }

            // Parse the request body if this is a form submission. Clients must set content-type to "x-www-form-urlencoded".
            requestBody = IOUtils.toString(this.getInputStream(), encoding);
            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(requestBody)) {requestBody = null;}
            logger.debug("Extracted HTTP request body: "+requestBody);
            if(request.getContentType() != null && request.getContentType().toLowerCase().contains(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)){
                addParameters(requestBody, encoding);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param requestBody
     * @param encoding
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void addParameters(String requestBody, String encoding) throws IOException {
        if(requestBody == null){
            return;
        }
        Matcher matcher = urlStrPattern.matcher(requestBody);
        while(matcher.find()){
            String decodedName = URLDecoder.decode(matcher.group(1), encoding);
            // If there's no value, matcher.group(2) returns an empty string instead of null
            String decodedValue = URLDecoder.decode(matcher.group(2), encoding);
            addParameter(decodedName, decodedValue);
            logger.debug("Parsed form parameter, name = "+decodedName+", value = "+decodedValue);
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param name
     * @param value
     */
    private void addParameter(String name, String value) {
        String[] pv = paramMap.get(name);
        if (pv == null) {
            pv = new String[]{value};
            paramMap.put(name, pv);
        }
        else {
            String[] newValue = new String[pv.length+1];
            System.arraycopy(pv, 0, newValue, 0, pv.length);
            newValue[pv.length] = value;
            paramMap.put(name, newValue);
        }
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper#getInputStream()
     */
    @Override
    public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        if (cachedBytes == null){
            cachedBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            IOUtils.copy(super.getInputStream(), cachedBytes);
        }

        // Return a inner class that references cachedBytes
        return new CachedServletInputStream();
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper#getReader()
     */
    @Override
    public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getInputStream()));
    }


    /**
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public String getRequestBody() {
        return requestBody;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper#getParameter(java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public String getParameter(String name) {
        if(paramMap.containsKey(name)){
            String[] value = (String[]) paramMap.get(name);
            if(value == null){
                return null;
            }
            else{
                return value[0];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper#getParameterMap()
     */
    @Override
    public Map<String, String[]> getParameterMap() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(paramMap);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper#getParameterNames()
     */
    @Override
    public Enumeration<?> getParameterNames() {
        return Collections.enumeration(paramMap.keySet());
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper#getParameterValues(java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public String[] getParameterValues(String name) {
        if(paramMap.containsKey(name)){
            return paramMap.get(name);
        }
        return null;
    }




    /**
     * Inner class that reads from stored byte array
     */
    public class CachedServletInputStream extends ServletInputStream {
        private ByteArrayInputStream input;

        public CachedServletInputStream() {
            input = new ByteArrayInputStream(cachedBytes.toByteArray());
        }

        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException {
            return input.read();
        }

        @Override
        public int read(byte[] b) throws IOException {
            return input.read(b);
        }

        @Override
        public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) {
            return input.read(b, off, len);
        }
    }
}
```

And add a filter to wrap the original request:

```
public class CustomFilter implements Filter {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CustomFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if(request!=null && request instanceof HttpServletRequest){
            HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

                            logger.debug("Wrapping HTTP request");
                request = new CustomHttpServletRequest(httpRequest);
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that you can share the details. I tried wrapping the HttpServletRequest but still is closed when calling after the pre-process inside the filter