# How can I modify the object of a post call in filter. Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a filter in my application

```
@Component
@Order(2)
public class RequestResponseLoggingFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(
      ServletRequest request, 
      ServletResponse response, 
      FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        // SET VALUE OF OBJECT
    }

    // other methods
}
```

I have a Restcall which uses a class.

```
@RequestMapping
Class Test{
  @PostMapping("/test")
  public void postEntry(@Valid @RequestBody Testing testing){
  }
}

Class Testing{
@NotNull(message="ERROR")  
String id;

....
}
```

I get the id in my filter and I would like to set the id of Testing class in my Filter. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can use `MockHttpServletRequest` something like this**

```
@Test
public void testAddEventWithWebAuthenticationDetails() {
    HttpSession session = new MockHttpSession(null, "test-session-id");
    MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
    request.setSession(session);
    request.setRemoteAddr("1.2.3.4");
    WebAuthenticationDetails details = new WebAuthenticationDetails(request);
    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("test-key", details);
    AuditEvent event = new AuditEvent("test-user", "test-type", data);
    customAuditEventRepository.add(event);
    List<PersistentAuditEvent> persistentAuditEvents = persistenceAuditEventRepository.findAll();
    assertThat(persistentAuditEvents).hasSize(1);
    PersistentAuditEvent persistentAuditEvent = persistentAuditEvents.get(0);
    assertThat(persistentAuditEvent.getData().get("remoteAddress")).isEqualTo("1.2.3.4");
    assertThat(persistentAuditEvent.getData().get("sessionId")).isEqualTo("test-session-id");
}
```

More examples [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest)

or

**if you want to do it filter way**

few Points Before that

- Request body can be read only once.
- If you read the body in a filter, the target servlet will not be able to re-read it and this will also cause IllegalStateException.
- You will need ServletRequestWrapper or its child: HttpServletRequestWrapper so that you can read HTTP request body and then the servlet can still read it later.

Workflow will be

- The only way would be for you to consume the entire input stream yourself in the filter.
- Take what you want from it, and then create a new InputStream for the content you read.
- Put that InputStream in to a ServletRequestWrapper (or HttpServletRequestWrapper).

  // Sample Wrapper class where you can read body and modify body content

  ```
   public class SampleHttpServletRequest 

          extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    private ByteArrayOutputStream cachedBytes;

    public SampleHttpServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
      super(request);
    }

    @Override
    public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
      if (cachedBytes == null)
        cacheInputStream();

        return new CachedServletInputStream();
    }

    @Override
    public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException{
      return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getInputStream()));
    }

    private void cacheInputStream() throws IOException {
      cachedBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      IOUtils.copy(super.getInputStream(), cachedBytes);
    }

    public class CachedServletInputStream extends ServletInputStream {
      private ByteArrayInputStream input;

      public CachedServletInputStream() {
        input = new ByteArrayInputStream(cachedBytes.toByteArray());
      }

      @Override
      public int read() throws IOException {
        return input.read();
      }
    }
  }
  ```

Filter class

```
public class MyFilter implements Filter {
  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    /* wrap the request in order to read the inputstream multiple times */
    MultiReadHttpServletRequest multiReadRequest = new MultiReadHttpServletRequest((HttpServletRequest) request);

    doMyThing(multiReadRequest.getInputStream());
    chain.doFilter(multiReadRequest, response);
  }
}
```

Refer these post for more detail

[Http Servlet request lose params from POST body after read it once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210645/http-servlet-request-lose-params-from-post-body-after-read-it-once)

[HttpServletRequestWrapper, example implementation for setReadListener / isFinished / isReady?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29208456/httpservletrequestwrapper-example-implementation-for-setreadlistener-isfinish?lq=1)

Comment: Thank you that was super helpful