# Springboot upgrade lead to Missing grant type error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

So i just upgraded SpringBoot version in a small project and the authentication is messed up now.
When I try to get an authentication token i get an error:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "Missing grant type"
}
```

I played around with postman. And if I move the grant_type/pw/username from the body to the Query Params it works fine. But we cannot change this. So is there any way to find out which dependency change caused this?
I checked the upgrade documents ([2.1->2.2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2-Release-Notes#upgrading-from-spring-boot-21) and [2.2 -> 2.3](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#upgrading-from-spring-boot-22)), but i can't find anything related to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was our code.

There is a limitation that restrict the request body so it is only readable once.

We had a workaround for that in a wrapper class that extends the `HttpServletRequestWrapper`. But if you upgrade the spring-boot version you will upgrade the embedded tomcat.

It turned out the we have to update our wrapper class, [here are the details about it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30748533/934347).
It works with the `2.3.3` Release. Maybe in the feature we have to maintain it again.