# Servlet - Logging inputstream in case of unMarshalException

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

Are there any good alternatives to log incoming body in case of unmarshalException instead of something like:

```
try{
   byteRequest = IOUtils.toByteArray(request.getInputStream());
   jaxbRequest = unMarshaller.unmarshal(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteRequest));
} catch (UnmarshalException ex) {
   LOG.error("Exception unmarshalling: {}", new String(byteRequest, "UTF-8"), ex);
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with this code ? (except String constructor is wrong)

Comment: Well, it copies the inputstream to a byteArray, which I might seem kinda unnecessary.

Comment: How about using filters ? But of course you have to copy inputstream there to avoid making it empty for afterwards as well, It's harder than this..

Comment: Here's an example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449096/how-to-read-inputstream-multiple-times

Comment: I would say that is the same kind of solution, just put somewhere else, but still a good idea.