# H2 console error: No suitable driver found for 08001/0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2

Hello Im having problem with viewing my schema in H2 console Database:

Im using spring boot:

```
spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MV_STORE=FALSE;MVCC=FALSE
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

this is my login page:

[image]

so what i see inside is standard console view , without my tables and yet my app is working fine.

Comment: Hi @filemonczyk, were you able to solve this?

Comment: tbh I dont remember the solution

Comment: I recommend to use direct connection to your H2 db [right from your IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43276769/5380322)...

Answer (score 5):

Usually "Test connection" is working (green line after login form), but connecting does not. This can be caused by handling of headers, which can be caused by filters or security config. For example, I was hit by this twice:

1. I have same symptoms and problem was caused by usage of logging. **Removing dependency** helped to get rid of *No suitable driver found for 08001/0* message while logging into h2-console:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
       <artifactId>logbook-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   ```

I am not sure, if it is bug of given [project](https://github.com/zalando/logbook/), or by wrong usage/config.

2. Configuring OAuth2 does hit me also. I need to exclude h2-console uri from web and also http security. See some [info here](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/10481). See snippets:

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableWebSecurity
   @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
           securedEnabled = true,
           jsr250Enabled = true,
           prePostEnabled = true
   )
   @RequiredArgsConstructor
   public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
       @Override
       public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
           web.ignoring().antMatchers("/h2-console/**");
       }
       @Override
       protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
           http
                   // only part of config is shown here...
                   .authorizeRequests()
                   .antMatchers("/",
                           "/error",
                           "/favicon.ico",
                           "/**/*.png",
                           "/**/*.gif",
                           "/**/*.svg",
                           "/**/*.jpg",
                           "/**/*.html",
                           "/**/*.css",
                           "/**/*.js",
                           "/h2-console/**")
                   .permitAll()
                   .antMatchers("/auth/**", "/oauth2/**").permitAll()
                   .anyRequest().authenticated()
                   .and()
                   .oauth2Login();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Dear Lubo, thank you very much! After using your solution, i can also start h2-database and the error is gone. Important ist, really NOT use the dependency as you said, and do add the block:  "@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/h2-console/**");
    }"

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was that I implemented a custom Filter (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804205/how-can-i-read-request-body-multiple-times-in-spring-handlermethodargumentresol), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210645/http-servlet-request-lose-params-from-post-body-after-read-it-once) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449096/how-to-read-request-getinputstream-multiple-times)) and the custom `HttpServletRequestWrapper` needs to take care of the H2 console login request which comes with the form data (including Driver Class input) and parse it as parameters:

```
public class MyHttpServletRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

private String body;

public MyHttpServletRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
    super(request);
    this.body = IOUtils.toString(request.getReader());
    //...
}

@Override
public Enumeration<String> getParameterNames() {
    if (!parsedParams)
        parseParams();

    List<String> result = Collections.list(super.getParameterNames());
    result.addAll(parameters.keySet());

    return Collections.enumeration(result);
}

private void parseParams() {
    if (!body.isEmpty()) {
        String[] rps = body.split("&");

        for (String rp : rps) {
            String[] kv = rp.split("=");
            try {
                parameters.put(kv[0], kv.length > 1 ? new String[]{URLDecoder.decode(kv[1], "UTF-8")} : new String[]{""});
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        parameters.setLocked(true);
        parsedParams = true;
    }
}

@Override
public Map<String, String[]> getParameterMap() {
    if (!parsedParams)
        parseParams();

    Map<String, String[]> s = super.getParameterMap();
    return Stream.concat(parameters.entrySet().stream(), s.entrySet().stream()).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
}

@Override
public String getParameter(String name) {
    return parameters.get(name) != null ? parameters.get(name)[0] : super.getParameter(name);
}

@Override
public String[] getParameterValues(String name) {
    String[] s = super.getParameterValues(name);
    return ArrayUtils.addAll(s, parameters.get(name));
}
}
```

Comment: Had a similar issue and I think I found a little simpler (read fewer new lines of code) workaround. In the constructor call one of the request methods that deals with parameters, e.g. getParameterNames or getParameter("anything"). For some reason, this wasn't working in the filter though. Haven't figured out why yet.

Comment: same, adding a simple logger statement logger.info(request.getParameterNames()); did the trick, it would be interesting to understand the rationale

Comment: confirmed: getParameterNames() internally calls `org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters()`. This does a lot of encoding and parsing stuff. And somehow that initialises something that .... solves the problem :-)

Comment: @kdefombelle Thanks a lot for that solution. I did not use logger. But just calling `request.getParameterNames()` solved my problem.

Comment: @Robert Were you able to find out anything more around that. I am lost how it fixes just by calling `request.getParameterNames()`.

Answer (score 1):

When I encountered this problem I was following a spring boot tutorial. In this tutorial, my spring boot guru used the following code in the application.properties:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:someName
```

The last line is not necessary because these are the default configurations done by spring boot:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb  
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver  
spring.datasource.username=sa  
spring.datasource.password=  
spring.h2.console.enabled=false
```

When I removed it, all worked as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding the problem and solution I had here, because I did not find any explicit mentions.

I had this problem when updating from Spring Boot 2.1 to 2.2.
(When testing I found the problem occurred even when switching from latest 2.1.13.RELEASE to 2.2.0.RELEASE.)

Analysis:
Our application uses both Jersey/JAX-RS and Spring Web.
To make this work:

- On Spring Boot 2.1 our application configured Jersey to use a servlet filter
  using (spring.jersey.type=filter) and the JerseyConfig used ServletProperties.FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404 to forward requests it couldn't handle to Spring Boot.
  This seems to break the h2-console in Spring Boot 2.x
- For Spring Boot 2.2, I removed the "spring.jersey.type=filter" configuration, so that Jersey uses a servlet instead.
  To make it play nice with Spring Web, I restricted Jersey using @ApplicationPath("/api") (all our JAX-RS requests start with that prefix anyway)

Answer (score 0):

From my end the issue was related to how logbook handles form request.

> > The LogbookFilter will, by default, treat requests with a application/x-www-form-urlencoded body not different from any other request, i.e you will see the request body in the logs. The downside of this approach is that you won't be able to use any of the HttpServletRequest.getParameter*(..) methods. See issue #94 for some more details.

The logbook team recomends setting up the system property

> > > As of Logbook 1.5.0, you can now specify one of three strategies that define how Logbook deals with this situation by using the logbook.servlet.form-request system property:

i.e

```java
java -jar -Dlogbook.servlet.form-request=parameter server/target/server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Answer (score -2):

Use entire String for connection in H2 Console i.e. , You will see only your tables

> jdbc:h2:~/test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MV_STORE=FALSE;MVCC=FALSE