# Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, spring

I have a controller which handles a long polling mechanism by using Springs `DeferredResult`. At times when I call the controller method multiple times I get the below exception :

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response`

So there is a call `views/getLongPollingGraphData` which passes some ids and returns with a json response for one or none id. When I load the page multiple times which makes this URL call some times I get the above exception.

The issue that I face is I am using the `onCompletion` callback on `DeferredResult` to remove the `DeferredResult` from a map when it either times out or the response is set on it. But in the case of this exception the `onCompletion` is not called and it stays on the map. I have read different So posts about this exception but I could not relate to any one of them.

Below is the entire stack trace of the exception and parts of my controller method.

```
Nov 07, 2016 9:52:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:213)
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:104)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:125)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:118)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:186)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:126)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.ClientAbortException_jsp._jspService(ClientAbortException_jsp.java:136)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:229)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:264)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:625)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl$1.run(AsyncContextImpl.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl.doInternalDispatch(AsyncContextImpl.java:382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.asyncDispatch(CoyoteAdapter.java:299)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.asyncDispatch(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1652)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Nov 07, 2016 9:52:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet main-dispatcher threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:213)
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:104)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:125)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:118)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:186)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:126)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.ClientAbortException_jsp._jspService(ClientAbortException_jsp.java:136)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:229)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:264)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:625)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl$1.run(AsyncContextImpl.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl.doInternalDispatch(AsyncContextImpl.java:382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.asyncDispatch(CoyoteAdapter.java:299)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.asyncDispatch(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1652)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Nov 07, 2016 9:52:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [main-dispatcher] in context with path [/test-web] threw exception [java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:213)
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:104)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:125)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:118)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:186)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:126)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.ClientAbortException_jsp._jspService(ClientAbortException_jsp.java:136)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:229)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:264)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:625)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl$1.run(AsyncContextImpl.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl.doInternalDispatch(AsyncContextImpl.java:382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.asyncDispatch(CoyoteAdapter.java:299)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.asyncDispatch(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1652)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "views/getLongPollingGraphData", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
@ResponseBody
public DeferredResult<WebServiceResponse> getLongGraphData(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        @RequestParam(value = "ids") String ids) 
    throws Exception
{
    //perform operations

    //set time out this DeferredResult, after 5 seconds 
    final DeferredResult<WebServiceResponse> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<WebServiceResponse>(5000L, awrDefault);
    //listOfViews is a list containing ids
    mMapOfDeferredResultAndViews.put(deferredResult, listOfViews);
    //more operations

    deferredResult.onCompletion(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            mMapOfDeferredResultAndViews.remove(deferredResult);
        }
    });

    return deferredResult;
}
```

**Edit:**
I think that a `org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException` is thrown at some point when the page is continuously refreshed. I use `org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` to handle it in a jsp page. Below is the code:

main-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.lang.Exception">Exception</prop>
            <prop key="org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException">ClientAbortException</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

ClientAbortException.jsp

```
<%@page import="org.slf4j.LoggerFactory"%>
<%@page import="org.slf4j.Logger"%>
<%@page import="com.test.model.messages.Messages"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Enumeration"%>
<%@page import="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper"%>
<%@page import="com.test.model.exceptions.TestException"%>
<%@page import="com.test.web.exchange.WebServiceResponse"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%
    Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    LOGGER.debug("Exception caught in JSP: ", (Exception) request.getAttribute("exception"));

    boolean bReturnJson = false;

    Enumeration<?> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();

    while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
        String headerName = (String) headerNames.nextElement();

        if (headerName.equals("accept")) {
            if (request.getHeader(headerName).equals(
                    "application/json; charset=utf-8")) {
                bReturnJson = true;
            }

            break;
        }
    }

    if (bReturnJson) {
        WebServiceResponse awsr = new WebServiceResponse();

        TestException exception = new TestException(
                Messages.ERROR.toString(),
                (Exception) request.getAttribute("exception"));

        awsr.setException(exception);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        out.write(mapper.writeValueAsString(awsr)); 
    } else {
        ((Exception) request.getAttribute("exception")).printStackTrace();
%>

HTML error!

<%
            }
%>
```

Comment: @ScaryWombat The `ClientAbortException.jsp` only resolves exceptions of kind `org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException`.

Comment: Your controller method simply throws Exception, where & how did you handle it ? Add the code for it here, we can look

Comment: @javaguy I updated the details in the question.

Comment: Why do you remove `deferredResult` in this line `mMapOfDeferredResultAndViews.remove(deferredResult);`? Is this need for you? How do you think it is may be cause of exception?

Comment: @AlykoffGali `mMapOfDeferredResultAndViews` maps the `DeferredResult` to corresponding views received. You see once the `DeferredResult` has returned or times out I don't need it. If I don't remove it  , it will sit in the map consuming memory for no reasons.

Comment: Where does `mMapOfDeferredResultAndViews` initialized and where does `deferredResult` is added to `mMapOfDeferredResultAndViews`?

Comment: Once possible solution for remove DeferredResult is to change type your `mMapOfDeferredResultAndViews` variable.

You may use `com.google.common.cache.LoadingCache<K,V>` from `google guava` library, in this library you may create cache with expiration time after write. see https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained

Comment: @AlykoffGali Thank you for your time. `DeferredResult` is set in a different thread(a consumer). The `mMapOfDeferredResultAndViews` is initialized in the `getLongGraphData` method, I guess I missed it in the question description, I will update it.

Comment: And using a third party library just to handle this issue, I guess might not be an elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is obvious:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getInputStream--

> Throws:
>       IllegalStateException - if the getReader() method has already been called for this request

To find out, which Filter (or something similar) calls the getReader() method before your JSP servlet does, set a break point to IllegalStateException. Call your JSP. In your debugger's call stack, find out the specific implementation class of the interface ServletRequest (this is container specific). Set a break point to getReader(), then call your JSP again and you got the root cause.

If you really have to call getReader() or getInputStream() multiple times, a HttpServletRequestWrapper might help you, see e.g.:

[How to read InputStream multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449096/how-to-read-inputstream-multiple-times)

https://gist.github.com/calo81/2071634

Without your whole project code no-one will be able to find out the cause for this Exception.