# How to get a String outside Filter in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, servlets, servlet-filters

```
@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        IOUtils.copy(request.getInputStream(), writer, "UTF-8");
        rawRequest = writer.toString();

        System.out.println("raw Request   :" + rawRequest);

        chain.doFilter(req, res);

    }
```

When I run this, I get the raw Request string in proper format, but when I try to get this raw Request anywhere outside the doFilter method, it returns null.

Is there a way I can get this String outside the doFilter method as well. I tried passing this String to a new method but nothing works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read request.getInputStream() multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449096/how-to-read-request-getinputstream-multiple-times)

Comment: what do you mean passing it to a new method? show more code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution would be to just add the raw request string that you just read into a ServletRequest attribute:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    IOUtils.copy(request.getInputStream(), writer, "UTF-8");
    rawRequest = writer.toString();

    System.out.println("raw Request   :" + rawRequest);

    req.setAttribute("rawRequest", rawRequest);

    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}
```

You can then recover it anywhere that you have access to the request object:

```
String rawRequest = (String)req.getAttribute("rawRequest");
```